# Rails: Get the time from a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

If I have a datetime value of something like 1/10/2011 9:00:00,  how do I get the 9:00 am from that datetime?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

strftime will do it.

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

All other attributes here:

http://www.wetware.co.nz/blog/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/

Answer (score 34):

```
DateTime.new(2011,10,1,9).to_s(:time) #=> "09:00"

DateTime.now.to_s(:time) #=> "11:58"
```

From [Time docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to search on the time from datetime

```
:conditions => ["created_at::time > ?",  "08:30" ]
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this before. Is this format (`created_at::time`) supported by the database or does Rails do some magic on it to generate the SQL statement? Does it only work with MySQL, or POSTgres, etc.?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Have not tested but most likely only works on Postgres (the `::` is casting `created_at` to `time`)

Comment: It's just converting to UTC:                                                                                    
[67] pry(main)> submissions.first.created_at
Mon, 30 Aug 2021 16:41:32 EDT -04:00
[70] pry(main)> submissions.first.created_at::time
2021-08-30 16:41:32 UTC

Answer (score 4):

You get time from date time using following code

```
datetime.strftime("%I:%M %P")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a string output, you can do like Hitesh and Chris said with `strftime`, but if you're trying to get an instance of `Time` from an instance of `DateTime` you can do the following:

```
Time.parse(DateTime.now.to_s)
```

If you're wanting to parse a string like `"1/10/2011 9:00:00"` and get an instance of `Time` back, you can use the same `parse` method:

```
Time.parse("1/10/2011 9:00:00") #=> 2011-10-01 09:00:00 -0500
```

Note the format: Ruby uses the non-US-friendly format of d/m/y when parsing dates.

To output a string representation of the time of day from that `Time` instance, it's back to `strftime`.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: It would be cool if you could ideally extract just a Time object without the associated date.

Comment: @Trip `Time` is not relative to the beginning of a day, though — it's a point in time. I agree a "time of day" conceptual interface to times would be beneficial.

Comment: @Trip Actually, there's a library here that seems to do it (I haven't played with it, just checked the README): https://github.com/JackC/tod

Comment: Ah nice recommend. Without throwing in another gem, I just save an object like this `time = Object.time.hour.hours + Object.time.minute.minutes` . Which gives me a seconds that I can add to a DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

I needed 24 hour time e.g. 11pm would return `"23"` (not 11)

```
Time.current.strftime("%H")
=> "18"
```

Answer (score 0):

**With translations**

If you use I18n you can easily define your [own time formats](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

> localize the time format you pass the Time object to `I18n.l` or (preferably) use Rails' `#l` helper. You can pick a format by passing the :format option
>
> ```
> # app/views/home/index.html.erb
> <h1><%=t :hello_world %></h1>
> <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p
> <p><%= l Time.now, format: :short %></p>
>
> # config/locales/pirate.yml
> pirate:
>   time:
>     formats:
>       short: "arrrround %H'ish"
> ```

Refer to @Chris Barretto's answer for the list of formatting options